# While loops inside an if-statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, while-loop

Beginner programmer here:)) I am working on a school project, where the assignment is to find the roots to five functions in one file.

In one of my functions there are two roots, and my code can only find one. It seems like the second while-loop is ignored. I've tried to put only this code in a separate file, and it worked - but together with the other files  it wont work...

Just ask if there is something that´s weird;)

```
def b(x: float):
    return -x**2+x+6

def bgraf():
    xlim(a1, b1)
    ylim(-15, 25)
    x = linspace(-5, 10, 1000)
    y = b(x)
    plot(x, y, 'r')
    return

funksjoner = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

while response not in funksjoner:
    i = int(input("choose a function from 0 to 4"))
    response = i
    if response in funksjoner:
        print("you chose function ", int(funksjoner[i]))

a1 = float(input())
b1 = float(input())
z = a1
y = b1
m = a1
n = b1
NP = True

if int(funksjoner[i]) == funksjoner[1]:
    while abs(y-z) > 1e-10:
        null1 = (z+y)/2
        if b(z)*b(null1)>0 and b(y)*b(null1)>0: 
            NP = False
            print('No roots in this interval')
            bgraf()
            break
        elif b(null1) == 0:
            break
        elif b(z)*b(null1)>0:
            z = null1
        else :
            y = null1
    while abs(n-m) > 1e-10:
        null1_2 = (m+n)/2
        if b(m)*b(null1_2)>0 and b(n)*b(null1_2)>0: 
            NP = False
            print('No roots in this interval')
            bgraf()
            break
        elif b(null1_2) == 0:
            break
        elif b(m)*b(null1_2)>0:
            m = null1_2
        else :
            n = null1_2
    if NP :
        print('we have a root when x =', round(((z+y)/2), 1))
        if null1 != null1_2:
            print('and when x =', round(((m+n)/2), 1))
        bgraf()
        scatter(null1, 0)
        if null1 != null1_2:
            scatter(null1_2, 0)
```

It looks like python is ignoring the second while-loop I placed under the if-statement. Is there another way I could this?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: This is far too broad. You'll need to narrow this down and mention what debugging you've already attempted.

Comment: Not sure but may be try print statements at various parts for example print `abs(n-m)` before while loop

Comment: You'll also have to provide all input. I'd suggest skipping input() altogether and just immeidately set the variables to whatever recreates the "error" you want to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to think about:

1. what do you want to achieve with the following line of code:
   If int(funksjoner[i]) == funksjoner[1]
   You could simply check 
   If i == 1
2. i don‘t see any difference between the first and the second while loop.
   z=m=a1
   y=n=a2
   So what should be the difference between those two?
3. In General the code is hard to read because of the naming of the variables, try to use variables which give you an impression what they contain.
4. For getting better impression what is going on in your code either use debugging, or if you are not familiar with debugging add print statements in your code to better understand what is stored in your variables at which time of the execution. And what statements are executed and which are skipped/not reached

When you give us more detailed information about your code (you could e.g. add comments to explain your code), have more detailed questions we can better support you

Comment: Thankyou very much Tanja! You helped me discover that I misplaced the m and n variables, and when I switched them the code worked:)) The reason I check if int(funksjoner[i]) == funksjoner[1] is because the number 1 is in a list the user can choose from. I have four more functions, and need to only include the function he/she chooses. But thankyou very much!!

Comment: I understood that you have user input that you want to check in this if statement. Nevertheless there is no sense in checking it the way you do.

Comment: ah, I get what you mean. I tried now and it worked, thanks again!

Comment: You could check e.g. if i==funktonjer[1] but in the end you do exactly the same as checking if i==1 but just in a more complicated way. If my answer helped you solve your question please accept my answer